# How to allow for optional services with Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am playing around with ASP.NET Core on my own hobby project, I want to create a framework that will be consumed by a developer, and I want to allow optional service and use defaults if they are not registered.

I am getting the `Unable to resolve service for type 'XXX'` error, but I would prefer the DI to return `null` rather then throw an exception.
I want to allow for optional services, so if a service is found, use that in the constructor, if not found, pass null into the constructor.

In my implementation I have:

```
public IServiceManager(IService service, ...)
{
    _service = service ?? new DefaultService();
    ...
}
```

So as you can see, if the service cannot be found (null) use the default.
Perhaps I am misunderstanding how DI works. Perhaps I could use a factory to do this instead?
However, in my system I using default services when non is provided will be a common occurrence, so I need a solution that doesn't require the consumer of the API to register a service.

Is there a way to configure ASP.NET Core DI to return null rather then throw an exception?

Comment: Are you getting the services you are trying to resolve from the `IServiceCollection`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By their very nature, constructor injection is always considered as mandatory.

The very first versions of the Microsoft DI (I don't like using the term ASP.NET Core DI, because it does not depend on ASP.NET Core and can be used outside of it) only supported the constructor with the most parameters.

I **think** this has been changed since then to allow multiple constructors and the IoC container will choose a fitting one. That being said, you'd likely need to define multiple constructors.

```
public IServiceManager(IService service, IOtherService otherService)
{
}

public IServiceManager(IOtherService otherService)
{
}
```

Then the second constructor should be called, if `IService` isn't registered with the IoC container.

But it's still quite a questionable practice at best and makes your code harder to maintain and hold its invariant/loose coupling.

You should never have to instantiate your types inside your services, not even for optional services.

Instead, you should provide registrations which allow a user to override them with their own implementations.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddTransient<IService, Service>();
    services.TryAddTransient<IOtherService, OtherService>();
}
```

Then the user override it.

```
services.AddTransient<IService, CustomService>();
services.AddMyLibrary();
```

Now `CustomService` will be injected where `IService` is requested.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! I have gone with multiple constructors as a temporary solution, but I will need to redesign and go with the `IServiceCollection` extension method in the future.
I have encountered a few interesting problems with DI, my application is mostly database configuration driven, so I use a lot of factories that read from the database

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. I tried this and introduced a bug. Using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, while I expected it to choose the constructor with the most parameters that it could satisfy, it chose the one with the fewest. When I switched to the most upvoted answer, it worked correctly.

Comment: @MatthewKane: Mind you having a look at the post date, it's been posted 5 years ago. implementation details as such may change over such long time (since they are not officially documented iirc, it means it may change between version). Second, I just tried it and it works, see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vLLLKr) for a proof. I don't know what you did try, but the posted answer still valid and working as in .NET 6

Answer (score 45):

Add default value to that parameter in the constructor.

```
public IServiceManager(IService service = null, ...)
{
  _service = service ?? new DefaultService();
  ...
}
```

Comment: This beats the idea of having Dependency Injection / IoC container in the firstplace, when you instantiate it inside the constructor

Comment: The default value will solve the problem OP was writing about. Actual implementation of the constructor is completely irrelevant. BTW, I'm not arguing whether instantiation of one type inside constructor of another type is or is not a good practice in the DI pattern.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, not with `null` but with `= new Sevice()`.
But I got the error `default parameter must be a compile time constant` :(

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien that has nothing to do with DI ... The compilation error says it clearly - default value for _any_ parameter of _any_ method in C# must be compile time constant - that is `null`, but not `new Sevice()`

Comment: Does not work, at least in net core 3.1, still get a di error upon startup

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to register the DefaultService *component* itself for the IService *service* within your IoC container - I'm using the terminology of Castle Windsor. Most of the containers allow to register multiple components for a service. In case you do not register a custom component for the service (another implementation of IService), DefaultService  will be resolved and injected; otherwise your custom component will be resolved for the service, just register the components in proper order (in Castle Windsor, the component registered first will be considered: [multiple components for a service](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md#register-more-components-for-the-same-service))

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(Component.For<IServiceManager>().ImplementedBy<ServiceManager>());
container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<CustomService>());
container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<DefaultService>());

IServiceManager serviceManager = container.Resolve<IServiceManager>();
IService service = ((ServiceManager)serviceManager).Service; // service is of type CustomService
```

Regarding the comment below from @Tseng:

> This beats the idea of having Dependency Injection / IoC container in the firstplace, when you instantiate it inside the constructor

It is not always the case... If you have an **optional dependency**, first, define it as a **property with a public setter**, so component can be injected if registered. In case there is no component registered (thus property is not set by the container), I think it can be acceptable to instantiate the default component via the "dangerous" new keyword. Everything is context-dependent - to be clear, I wouldn't instantiate a service manually, but there are always exceptions.

Comment: First, MSDI doesn't support property or method injections at all (and likely never will), so for this one needs a 3rd party controller like Autofac. Depending on the IoC container this may or may lead to leak infrastructure into your services (i.e. some containers require the use of attributes such as `[Inject]` or similar to be declared on these properties or to relaxing of encapsulation (having public setter for the property).

Comment: The second issues comes from the usage of `new`. In order to be able to `new`ing a default implementation one would have to relax encapsulation to do so. If we assume that the injected service is an DAL one (ie a repository, like `SqlServerRepository` for example), in order to instantiate this inside a domain service, you'd suddenly have to reference the DAL project/assembly from your domain. Now here the alarm bells should ringing that you are one step away from doom and now have tight coupling to other layers. This leads to badly designed software and troubles comes at a later moment

Comment: I'm not sure if Castle Windsor supports .NET Core yet. I have used Windsor before and am looking a which solution to use. AutoFrac has good documentation for .NET Core so I may try that when I get round to it. http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html
But then again, I also want to keep dependencies to a minimum, I'm not sure of the advantages of third party IoC Vs native .NET DI